# How do I cut a 45 degree bevel on a table saw with consistent dimensions?

Tags: table-saw, tolerance

I tried making consistent 45 degree bevels to create a cube. Cutting all edges of 6 perfect squares on the table saw with blade tilted. I also used a guide. But, regardless, there were slight variations in each piece making for an imperfect cube.

What are the finer points to using a table saw for bevel cuts?

How do I cut a 45 degree bevel on a table saw with consistent dimensions?

Comment: @AstPace http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/1467/1250 would be the answer. Anyways, the question is not clear about what the imperfections were or why planing / sanding after cutting wasn't working.

Comment: i changed the word to bevel to try to be more clear.

Comment: To use a waxie digital level you table saw must be perfectly level. I just use a cast iron 45 degree bevel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do this a lot. That is, I cut 24 bevels on 6 squares of wood.

The first trick is get your blade set at a 45 degree angle.  Since I started using a digital level (Wixie Digit) it has made the task much easier. Otherwise, you would need to make repeated cuts on scrap until you get your angle. (Two pieces placed bevel to bevel will form a right angle that you can check with a try-square.)

[image: Using the digital level at 45 degrees]

The next trick is to use a dedicated sled with the slot cut at 45 degrees to the saw table top. It doesn't have to be a full size sled unless you are making large cubes.  My sled also has lever-clamp and an adjustable stop (held in position by the two wing-nuts).  It's hard to see the piece under the clamp, but it's there.  Notice I have stop block clamped into the saw slot to prevent overrun and the blade guard behind the sled fence. The blade has not been lowered, yet, since it was raised to set the tilt angle.

[image: The sled]

Gives me perfect 45 degree beveled pieces every time.

[image: Clamped assemblage]

Then I glue the pieces together using yellow glue and clamp with rubber bands.